# What security risk does a missing SSL connection pose when using the program 'barrier'?

Tags: networking, vpn, ssl

I'm a beginner regarding networks but I would like to understand the subject more deeply.

The program 'barrier' allows me to use mouse and keyboard from one laptop to work on another when the cursor leaves the screen:

https://snapcraft.io/barrier

It connects to the other laptop via an internal IP (192.168.x.x)

Unfortunately, I can't get it to work with SSL activated, which is usually an option.

Also, I have noticed it doesn't work with my VPN activated unless I use split tunneling, making the VPN ignore the connection from that application. Does that mean the traffic leaves my network and is visible outside of my router?

I can't imagine that but I'm not 100% sure. If it stays on my network, could somebody else who broke into it see the traffic between the two laptops that Barrier forwards? I assume yes. Would that include passwords?

Both laptops run a Debian based Linux distribution and use my home's WiFi. No one else but me uses that router/network and the password is strong.

Answer (score 2):

The program connects to systems inside the local network. Not using SSL to protect the connection inside the local network is a risk if somebody you don't trust has access to the network. This is typically the case in more or less public networks (internet cafe, university, WiFi hotspots ...) but it might also be the case at home if you don't trust family members or if your local WiFi is not properly secured against others.

As for the need for Split-VPN: the systems need to be able to communicate together inside the local network and a VPN which includes all traffic is in the way of this. If you restrict the non-VPN part in the Split-VPN to only the local network, then it is sufficiently secure, i.e. all internet facing traffic should still pass through the VPN.

Comment: Thank you! Upon further inspection the VPN even has an option to allow all internal network traffic. That makes sense. But a great explanation from you, I understand it much better now.